# Query check if there's a path between 2 nodes after an edge / node is removed

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, undirected-graph

**Question:**

Given an undirected graph with N nodes and M edges. Given Q queries, there are 2 types of query:

- 1 - A - B - U - V

Check if there's a path between the node A and B after you remove the edge U-V

- 2 - A - B - X

Check if there's a path between the node A and B after you remove the node X

Constraints:

```
N <= 100000
M <= 500000
Q <= 100000
```

**P/S:**

I think that the only way there's path between A and B after the removal is that A, B is in the same [Biconnected Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) or the edge/node is not a bridge/arc.

But since we only have logN time for each query (because there're at most 100.000 queries), I can't find a way to check if A, B is in the same Biconnected Component in O(logN).

Is there a way to do it? Or is there a different solution to this problem?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity)?

Comment: You're on the right track; it's biconnected components on the original graph, least common ancestors, and a whole lotta details. (@גלעדברקן, those algorithms could also work, but they're IMO more complicated, and the constants are bad.)

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to do this is a depth first search, starting at A and stopping and returning true if it reaches B, returning false if B cannot be reached.

It would be useful to know what your actual performance requirement is in seconds.

The [PathFinder Graph Theory Engine](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder) can check if two random nodes are connected in a graph containing 403,394 nodes and 3,387,388 links with a mean time 0.14 seconds ( 100 tests of different random nodes )

Your graphs are about 4 to 10 times smaller, so I guess it could be done in well under a tenth of a second.

For 100,000 queries that would be less than 3 hours.

You would have to post you test graph to get a more accurate measure of performance.